# xcode 4.x.x Project Navigator - use real folders

Tags: xcode, directory, project-navigator

Is there a way to make xcode use real folder hierarchies in the Project Navigator?
I'm finding these pseudo folders somewhat annoying because they do not reflect the project on disk.
Or at least have the xcode-made-folders a different color than the real folders?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need to manage folders on disk ? You can do everything in Xcode (adding, rename, organize, deleting)

Comment: Prior to xcode I worked a lot with a program that used a disk navigator equivalent window. I got used to it and liked the 1:1ness of working that way.
I do see the advantages of having in-project folders, at times it is easier to work with, but if you have to import a bunch of code in a hierarchy segment from one project to another, the folder structure has to be recreated for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, although they *are* colored differently.

You have groups (yellow) -- which *can* refer to a directory, but does not update automatically to reflect what's on disk. Groups can also represent a group which has no relation to a directory or the structure of its contents.

You also have a reference (blue). This updates automatically, but its *contents* are not first class project items.

Personally, I just structure projects such that they can be (re)constructed from an on-disk representation easily (e.g. drop the folder), or in another IDE. Quite often, details which *could* (unnecessarily) be defined in Xcode are moved outside of the xcodeproject. Synchronizing the representation in the Project Navigator is about as easy as drag and drop once you work out how to structure the program/sources/targets.

**Edit:** I am referring to the Project Navigator. Whether what you refer to as the "project organizer" means the Project Navigator or some part of the Organizer, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for that, I confuse organizer with navigator (made the corrections)
It used to color folders yellow and blue, now since 4.3.2 it doesn't do it anymore.

Comment: @Dabbu ah. missed that change -- I am using 4C199/4.2 on 10.6 right now.

Answer (score 1):

***Making a folder structure mimic your Project Navigator group structure:***

For this procedure, as always, **make a backup of your whole project folder before doing this** (a zipped Archive in Finder does nicely).

What you want is easy to set up for new files added to or created by the project, but it can be a mess if you already have a lot of files in the groups you want, but not in the disk folders you want.

If you hilite a group in Project Navigator, move your attention over to Utilities pane > File Inspector > Identity. The key area is dealing with Paths. The popup will give you various relative paths to the default location of the group's files, and Full Path will always give you just that. In a fresh project you'll find that any groups created all have the same location assigned.

Now the key here is the little window icon button just under the popup (to the very right). If you click that you can choose a (folder) location for files in that group. If you already have files in that group they will *not* be moved to the new location, but will instead turn red in Project Navigator because the files on disk are not in the newly assigned path for the group, but moving them into the folder you just set up for the group should fix you back up.

(Tip: The little arrow button is a shortcut to "Reveal in Finder")

Now, when you make a "New File...", after selecting what type of file you want (Next), then configure whatever setting apply for that type (Next), you're presented with a sheet asking where to place the new file(s). If you have that group selected in Project Navigator before you begin this process, it will already be selected as the item in the "Group" popup at the bottom of the sheet, and the folder associated with that group will be selected in the file browser. If you decide you want it in a different group (I do that all the time because I won't have the proper group selected in Project Navigator before I get to this point), just change it in the Group popup at the bottom and the file browser will change to the folder associated for the group you just selected.

If you later make a sub-group of a group in Project Navigator, it will default to the path of the parent group. If a sub-group already exists when you set the path of the parent group, the paths for any existing sub-groups will *not* move with the parent.

Avoid duplicate files: If you want to move existing files into another group (that already has a path assigned to it) and also move the files into the group's folder on disk, you have a choice at this point. You can go ahead and delete them from Project Navigator, making sure you only delete the reference to them and move on to the next step, or as an option, you can actually move them in Project Navigator to the group you want them in (this doesn't change disk location of the files -- the folder associated with the group only applies to new files for the group) and use them as a guide for what still needs to be dragged in from the Finder. This can come in handy if you are going to be moving a lot of existing files around, as you'll see in a moment.

Now, in Finder, manually move some files into the folder that they should end up in (the folder associated with the new group). If you moved them over in Project Navigator (instead of removing them), they will turn red because the actual files are not at the place they were, but this can be a guide (especially if you're moving a lot of files around) for what still needs to be set properly.

Now, you can drag and drop them from Finder onto the group that's associated with the folder where you put the files. In the dialog that comes up, it doesn't matter if the checkbox is checked or not for copy (if necessary), since they are already in place, but it IS important to make sure you have the "Add to targets" checkbox(es) checked.

If you deleted the files (remove reference only) from the old group you can go into the old group's folder in Finder and drag the files from there to the new group in Project Navigator, you will need to make sure Copy if necessary is checked, but this is where end up with duplicate files on disk… In both the old group's folder and the new group's folder. This is why you want to move them to the new location first in Finder before dragging them into the new group in Project Navigator.

If you left the red files in Project Navigator sitting in the proper group, after you add the same files onto the group (copy to group not necessary since they're already in the proper location) you will end up with new (black) references to the files as well as red broken references to the same files. At this point you can just delete the red files from the group without being asked if you want to delete the files or just the reference. Leaving the red files in the new group until you have the proper (black) files showing up alongside them in Project Navigator can help to make sure that you get all of your files back into the Project Navigator.

If you're only shuffling around a couple/few files, then once you have the files moved in both the Project Navigator and in Finder to the proper locations, you can select each red reference in Project Navigator and choose the path for that particular file (in the same manner as you assigned a folder to a group). But, if you're moving around a bunch of files, this can take a long time (you can only assign one at a time), so it's better to just drop them in from Finder.

One more gotcha to look out for… It's best to just leave everything alone that sits in the "Supporting Files" group, as well as MainMenu.xib, since these are all expected to be in specific locations according to the Build Settings.

Remember: **Always make sure you have a backup first** (things can get out of hand if you are shuffling a LOT of files around)... Just having a snapshot probably won't help since reverting to a snapshot won't move your files on disk back to where the originally were.

Comment: "zipped Archive"?! Have you heard anything about `git`?